# How can I integrate Azure AD into my app which implements SSO using AWS Cognito?

Tags: php, azure, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

Currently my web application ties into Amazon Cognito and validates against users directly stored in Amazon IAM.

I need to extend it to support validating against a third party's Azure AD (and hopefully not having to import all the users into Cognito since that may not be feasible). Currently, I've been exploring and found that I can [add the Azure AD as a federated IdP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial), though it seems like it requires that users be setup both in AWS and AD and mapped per the tutorial, but a comment from Jaffadog notes:

> "Nice tutorial. However, it incorrectly suggests that you need to
>   create or provision accounts in AWS in order for federated login to
>   work - which is false. When login into AWS using SAML federated login,
>   the user merely assumes the AWS role present in the SAML assertion. No
>   AWS IAM user account is required before login, and none shall be
>   created as a consequence of login either."

Will this solution work if I want to keep my Azure AD users just in Azure, and keep my AWS users in AWS? There's conflicting information on how user provisioning works between AWS and AD.

Otherwise, if not is my only other solution to host my own SAML service (using something like SimpleSAML)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using ADFS for single signon with Active Directory and the Amazon Management Console is the recommended solution. You specifically mention Azure AD which I have not personally tested.

[EDIT after new question]

AWS uses group names that start with "AWS-" to assign privileges. This means that you do have to do some work on the Active Directory side creating groups and adding users to groups. Then you need to create an IAM Role for each AD group. IAM does not import users from AD, just maps AD groups to IAM roles.

This article will walk you thru setting up everything using Active Directory.

[Enabling Federation to AWS Using Windows Active Directory, ADFS, and SAML 2.0](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enabling-federation-to-aws-using-windows-active-directory-adfs-and-saml-2-0/)

Here are a couple of articles that specifically cover Azure AD and AWS:

[AWS Best Practice: Azure AD SAML Authentication Configuration for AWS Console](http://blog.flux7.com/aws-best-practice-azure-ad-saml-authentication-configuration-for-aws-console)

Comment: But how does user provision work? If I have ~500 users in Azure AD, do they get imported as each user logs in through AWS?

Comment: So I'm configuring this for a client who will ultimately host / manage the Azure AD. Is the first article still relevant because it covers setting everything up in Windows? Can I not just configure it through the Azure Portal?

Comment: Also, the second article doesn't have any mention of user provisioning. Is that required for logging in from AWS Cognito (using a user stored in Azure AD)? It seems like it's just for Azure AD to AWS, or does it work both ways? Still confused on "Federation" vs SSO